# Prove or disprove: $\sup\left \{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x^2-5x+6\leq0 \right \}=3$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, limsup-and-liminf, supremum-and-infimum

No homework:http://www2.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~gaggle/S15/MATHINFO/UEBUNG/nachholklausur.pdf

> Prove or disprove: $\sup\left \{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x^2-5x+6\leq0 \right\} =3$

I would say the statement is true because if we use the p-q-formula:

$$x_{1,2}= \frac{5}{2}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{-5}{2}\right)^2-6}$$

$$x_{1,2}= 2.5\pm\sqrt{\frac{25}{4}-6}$$

$$x_{1,2}= 2.5\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}$$

$$x_{1,2}= 2.5\pm\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

$$x_1=3$$

$$x_2=2$$

Actually, I don't really understand the statement, what is it saying?
That the supremum of the function is 3?

Then statement is wrong because we got as second solution 2 which is smaller than 3, so the supremum is 2 and not 3..?

Comment: $$  x^2 - 5x + 6 = (x-2)(x-3) $$

Comment: Please draw a graph of $y = x^2 - 5 x + 6.$ It should start to make sense after that.

Comment: The supremum is the largest value in the set (or more correctly the smallest value which is greater than or equal to any other value in the set).  It is like asking "Where is the top edge."  You should be able to tell that the set of $x$'s which satisfy the inequality is $\{x~:~2\leq x\leq 3\}=[2,3]$.  Where is the upper bound?

Comment: $\{x\in \Bbb R\mid x^2-5x+6\leq0\}$ is the solution set to the inequality $x^2-5x+6\leq0$. You are asked to find the supremum of that solution set.

Comment: Review what a supremum/least upper bound of a set is.  The supremum can't be 2 because 2.1 and others are all also in the set, so 2 is not an upper bound.

Comment: The supremum has nothing (directly) to do with solving the function.  You need to prove 2 things: a) if $x^2 - 5x + 6 \le 0$ then $x \le 3$.  b) if $y < 3$ then there must exist a $z $ $;y < z$ such that $z^2-5z+6 \le 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement to prove or disprove is, reformulated, equivalent to the following two conditions

- if $x$ is a real solution to $x^2-5x +6\leq 0$, then $x\leq 3$;
- if $x>3$, then is not a solution to $x^2-5x +6$.

The statement is true: solving $x^2-5x +6 = 0$, we see that the only two solutions are $2$ and $3$. As the polynomial function is negative between the root, we have 
$x^2-5x +6 \leq 0$ if, and only if, $x\in[2,3]$.

*Here is the graph of the polynomial function $f$ defined by $f(x)=x^2-5x +6$. The set $S\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \{x: f(x) \leq 0\}$ is the part of the $x$-axis for which the curve is below $0$. Since $S=[2,3]$, we have $\sup S = \sup [2,3] = 3$.*

[image: Plot of $f$]

Comment: Thank you! So it was enough I used p-q-formula and showed the function has 2 solutions which are both smaller-equal to 3, right?

Comment: Yes. You find the two solutions to $x^2-5x+6=0$, namely 2 and 3; from there, the set $S\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\{x\in\mathbb{R}: x^2-5x+6 \leq 0\}= [2,3]$. Therefore, $\sup S = \sup [2,3] = 3$.

Comment: If it would say in the task that sup = 2, then it would be wrong statement, right?
Since "The supremum is the largest value in the set".

Comment: Yes, 2 would be wrong (this is the $\inf$ of the set). Note that you gave in your comment above the definition of the *maximum*: the supremum is more general and has a slightly subtler definition, as the *least upperbound*. (It coincides with the maximum **if** the maximum exists, but for some sets the $\sup$ exists but not the $\max$: think e.g. of $(0,1)$.)

Comment: Clement, I answered just to put a visible graph, you added one while I was fiddling. I did add a second question on the same topic, putting the graph first. It might help the OP.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, I saw your graph after I edited my answer... I am rather slow at plotting (especially given the time Mathematica takes to start), so tend to add plots afterwards.

Comment: I erased the duplicate graph and left the follow-up exercise. Maybe the OP will look at it, I won't hold my breath. Oh, and this desmos site is very good at graphs, very quick to get it right.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what to say next. I am pasting in a graph of $y = x^3 - 3x.$ What is 
$$\sup\left \{ x\in\mathbb{R}|x^{3}-3x\leq0 \right
\}?$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for making special task for me :D
I can't solve now because I go sleep and also because I will read about sup and inf (it's currently 00:21 here in Germany).
I promise will try to solve your task tomorrow, I mean, it's been made for me and I will do it!

Comment: $x^{3}-3x=x(x^{2}-3)$ $\Rightarrow$ $x_{1}=0$ $\wedge$ $x_{2}=\sqrt{3}$
$\Rightarrow$ $S=\left \{0, \sqrt{3}\right \}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sup \left \{0, \sqrt{3} \right \} = \sqrt{3}$

I hope it's correct?

Comment: @cnmesr The supremum is correct (it is indeed $\sqrt{3}$), but the derivation is not. The roots of the polynomial $P(X) = X^3-3X$ are $\{-\sqrt{3},0,\sqrt{3}\}$; from there, you can show that $P(x)\leq 0$ iff $x\in(-\infty,-\sqrt{3}]\cup [0,\sqrt{3}]$. The supremum of this set $(-\infty,-\sqrt{3}]\cup [0,\sqrt{3}]$, in turn, is $\sqrt{3}$. Looking at the graph is a good sanity check to verify what the set is.